# Подскажите, как сделать затемнение фона? (полупрозрачным цветом)

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, веб-дизайн

Сейчас на многих сайтах используется такое затемнение, но я не нашел, как его сделать. Например у header есть картинка на фоне, а поверх нее текст. Но чтобы текст читался, поверх картинки накладывается полупрозрачный черный например фон. Как его сделать? Для header имеются такие свойства:

```
header {
    height: 538px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/header-bg.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как исключить применение стиля к дочерним селекторам CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776052/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-css)

Answer (score 9):

например:

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  background: url(https://amazingcarousel.com/wp-content/uploads/amazingcarousel/3/images/lightbox/golden-wheat-field-lightbox.jpg) center no-repeat;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}

header:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  z-index: 2;
}

.inner {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px;  
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="inner">
    <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor.</h1>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Reiciendis, eligendi.</span>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 5):

Это ответ на ваш вопрос:

```
background: linear-gradient( rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5) ), url('/img/back/home-back.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: top;
```

Answer (score 1):

Наложить полупрозрачный блок c rgba бэкграундом (где 4й параметр прозрачность) и с абсолютным позиционированием.
HTML:

```
<div class="header">
<div class="cover"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header{
position: relative;
}
.cover{
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
}
.content{
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: отличный простой вариант, но он затемняет и весь остальной контент, и z-index-ом почему-то не регулируется...

Comment: Отредактировал, думаю так понятней. Мы накладываем блок поверх.

Answer (score 1):

Тоже понадобилось такое решение, в итоге не подходили предложения через `::after`, `position` и `z-index`. В этих случаях нужно все элементы на странице поднимать на позицию выше. Через `filter` и `opacity` тоже не вариант, затемняется всё.
Решение простое.

```
  background:  url('../img/header/bg.jpg') no-repeat center /cover, #555555;
  background-blend-mode: hard-light;//или multiply
```

Можете хоть зелёной сделать. И ни где ничего не надо менять.

Answer (score 0):

Добавляешь черную заливку фона и `opacity: значение от 0 до 1;` для этого фона . Пример: полупрозрачность `opacity: 0.5;`

Comment: Не работает. Применяется или фоновая картинка, или цвет. Но не вместе. background: url(../img/header-bg.png) no-repeat center center;
 background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать с помощью псевдоэлемента. Код будет примерно такой:

```css
header {
    height: 538px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(../img/header-bg.png) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    position: relative;
}
header:after{
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    background: black;
    opacity: 0.5;
    z-index: 1;
}
.content{
    position: relative;
    color: white;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="content">
    тут контент
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

RGBA();

например, `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);`

Answer (score 0):

Можно попробовать

```
filter: brightness(60%);
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]