# как исключить применение стиля к дочерним селекторам CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

Вопрос для фронтендщиков крайне простой:

Вот есть у меня header, внутри него есть

текст , я изменяю opacity header'a в css , но также меняется opacity у

, что конечно же логично, но вот как сделать так, чтобы хедер поменял свой стиль, а его внутринности (в этом случае текст) нет?

Я пытался вернуть

opacity на 100% ,но она не делается....

```
header {
    background-color: blue;

    opacity: 0.7;
}

header > p {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На мой взгляд это самый универсальный вариант.
Конечно хороший вариант предложил `St1myL` `background-color: rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.5);`, но это сработает только, если `background` одним цветом, а если картинка?

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
}

#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  /*background: blue;*/
  background: url(https://cdn.wallpapershdin.com/wallpapers/landscapes-cityscapes-buildings-hong-kong-cities-1366x768.jpg);
  background-position: 50%;
  opacity: .4;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  position: absolute;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="wrapper"></div>
  <p>
    lorem
  </p>
</header>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, да CSS не так прост, поеду-ка я дальше его изучать :-)

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...

Answer (score 2):

Для изменения прозрачности фона можно использовать rgba. Последнее число управляет прозрачностью(от 0 до 1)

```css
header {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 100, 0.5);
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</p>
</header>
```

Comment: Помогло спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Если нужно с opacity можно сделать так:

```
header:before {
    background-color: blue;
    z-index: -1;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0.1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```