# Как реализовать прозрачность hover, но чтобы она не влияла на border и надпись?

Tags: css, вёрстка, hover

```css
.btn {
  height: 39px;
  border: 2px solid #202328;
  color: #202328;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.75px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: #63FFD1;
  opacity: 0.59;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Забронировать</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как исключить применение стиля к дочерним селекторам CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776052/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-css)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.btn {
  height: 39px;
  border: 2px solid #202328;
  color: #202328;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.75px;
  position: relative;
}

.btn:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #63FFD1;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: opacity .3s ease;
}

.btn:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.btn:hover:before {
  opacity: 0.59;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Забронировать</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Представьте ваш цвет фона в `rgba` и задайте ему прозрачность:

```css
.btn {
  height: 39px;
  border: 2px solid #202328;
  color: #202328;
  text-decoration: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  font-size: 15px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  letter-spacing: 0.75px;
}

.btn:hover {
  background-color: rgba(99, 255, 209, 0.59);
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <a href="#" class="btn">Забронировать</a>
</div>
```