# HTML + CSS прозрачный фон

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, прозрачность

Такая структура:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="children">
        <span class="info-name">name</span>
        <span class="info-price">price</span>
     </div>
</div>
```

У `parent` фоном стоит картинка. Внутри `parent` еще один `<div>`, но его фон закрывает картинку. Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы фон внутреннего `<div>` был полностью прозрачен ? 
Если использовать `opacity`, то прозрачными становяться и `<span>` c текстом внутри `children`, но их прозрачными делать не надо.

Comment: `.children{background: transparent;}`

Comment: `.children{background-color: transparent}`

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [как исключить применение стиля к дочерним селекторам CSS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/776052/%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc-css)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.children{background:transparent}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое ! Работает !